# admob null pointer exception on few devices

Tags: android, admob

My apps are force closing on few devices(samsung & sony) after implementing interstitial ads and the stack traces from developer console is as follows.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.ads.a.f$a.run(SourceFile:128)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't understand why it is happening. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the new Google Play Services library which now include the Admob classes.
The Admob package has changed so your imports will need to be adjusted to

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
```

Comment: I installed the latest Play services from SDK manager. But when I add the above import statement, an error is thrown that this(import com.google.android.gms.ads.*) package can't be resolved

Sorry for late reply, i was out of town.

Comment: You need to add the Play Services library from the SDK Manager into your project.

Comment: thanks a ton. now i don't get the crash reports from my users